# JavaFX через Maven

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, maven

Хочу сделать проект на JavaFX через Maven, чтобы не нужно было на каждый компьютер скачивать JavaFX отдельно. Выдаёт ошибку `Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`, насколько я понимаю, надо добавить VM options с path-to-javafx/lib, но разве даже с Maven оно должно быть прописано?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>SkiBaseInterface</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>17-ea+9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>17-ea+9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>sample.NewMain</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Может дело в том, что компилятор 15й версии, а fx взята для 17й

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не нужно было на каждый компьютер скачивать JavaFX отдельно, сделайте сборку через jlink и включите туда все свои библиотеки.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]